# Compiler log file, bltTable in Modelica

Tags: modelica

I get no error when I simulate the model on Twinbuilder with Modelica. But as you can see in the below image, there is no progress of the solution. [image]

I want to investigate possible reasons of this situation. I generated a compiler log file and solver log file.

In the bltTable, it can be seen there is a red marked region on the diagonal line which describes problematic equations and variables. But I can`t understand what measures I should take by looking at this table. I add blt table in the below image [image]

Do you know how to deal with these red regions on the diagonal line?
I attach blt table as attached.

https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/903907/bltTable.html

Comment: This table is also known as incidence matrix in some other publications. On the left you have your equations, on the top you have your variables. Whereever you have variables above the diagonal, you have a nonlinear loop or block. In your example, there are two variables above the diagonal, these are your iteration variables for solving the nonlinear block. Nonlinear loops cannot always be avoided, this is not necessarily a problem.